# angular - how to get rid of unsafe links

Tags: angular

Has html code

```
    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let ads of adsX">
          <ng-container *ngIf="ads.telegram">
             <a href="tg://resolve?domain={{ ads.telegram }}"> {{ ads.telegram }} </a>
          </ng-container>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

I get an unsafe link **(unsafe:tg://resolve?domain=telegram)**

How to make a link secure **(tg://resolve?domain=telegram)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DomSanitizer:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
...
getTelegramLink(link:string){
    const fullLink = `tg://resolve?domain=${link}`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

and then in your template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let ads of adsX">
    <ng-container *ngIf="ads.telegram">
      <a [href]="getTelegramLink(ads.telegram)">{{ ads.telegram }}</a>
    </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```